# Openflow : Creating a flow Tee

Tags: openflow, opendaylight, ryu

I want to create a flow Tee in a switch to send packets to an IDS.

That is, I want the following effects:

1. When packet comes into the switch match on source MAC.
2. If MAC matches make two copies of the packet:

   1. For one of the copies, rewrite the target IP address and goto table 2.
   2. For another copy Just goto table 2 without rewriting anything.

What is the best way to achieve this using OpenFlow?

Can a single instruction have multiple goto targets so the packet and a copy of it gets sent to two different tables?

Ranga.

Answer (score 0):

I dug around and discovered multiple goto in a single flow is forbidden but you can have a goto and an output to a port. That is how you would create a flow tee.